# How do you align normal text with bulleted text?

Tags: itemize

[image]

So I want to align the text in orange with the bulleted text in blue. So how do i do it. Also i am using two rows in Latex

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). FYI, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.

Comment: By mowing items labels outside of text area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a standard list, then you can use `\item []` to place text that is aligend with the bulleted list:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item [] Third item with the list
\end{itemize}%

\begin{itemize}
    \item [] Fourth item aligned with other items
\end{itemize}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It actually works!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, than you after for the following:

[image]

In above example labels are simple moved outside of text area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
     
     Third item with the list
\end{itemize}%

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```